# How can I get Eclipse to mark generated code like equals to prevent code quality tooling issues?

Tags: eclipse, annotations, sonarqube, generated-code

Generated code tends to flag up in our SONAR code quality tooling for things like cyclomatic complexity. It seems that it is a recognised problem and there is support for annotation-based suppression.

I don't want to have to manually edit or annotate this code to prevent these warnings. How can I change the generated code produced by Eclipse to include say a `@Generated` or `@SuppressWarnings("all")` annotation whenever it generates code for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a central place in Eclipse config where you can specify some flags that should be added when Eclipse generates code for you.

The only way to kind-of achieve what you want is to modify each code templates of "Java > Editor > Templates" and surround them with some flags like "// SONAR-OFF" and "// SONAR-ON", and to configure the [Sonar Switch-Off Violations plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin) accordingly.

But:

- This is quite a pain to modify all those templates (even if you'll do it only once)
- This won't work for advanced code generation like for "equals" or "hashCode" method

Comment: Unfortunately it's those kinds of methods I would want to annotate. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @fabrice This answer is now some years old. Has something changed?